# Generating _escaped_fragment_ query string using nginx URL rewriting

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, fragment-identifier

I would like to manually produce the _escaped_fragment_ query parameter for search bots \ crawlers that don't implement _escaped_fragment_ support on their own.

Using nginx, I tried to do the most obvious, yet it didn't work.
Couldn't find any replication of this post anywhere.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* (LinkedInBot|UnwidFetchor|voyager)){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ ?_escaped_fragment=$1
        #Reverse proxy to phantom instance
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do a rewrite with a leading `?`, try pre-pending with index

```
if (foo) {
  rewrite ^ /index.php?_escaped_fragment=$1 last;
  #the remaining config
}
```

Comment: if I do that, then the `proxy pass` statement will be ignored also, wouldn't it?